# Objective-C - is it okay to not have a return for a method?

Tags: objective-c

I have a method that returns an object, like

```
- (myObject *) doStuff: (NSString *)x
```

This method creates an entry on an array and also returns the object created, so I can do other things with it after running the method, but at some point in my code I don't need the reference it returns, so, instead of using

```
myObj1 = [doStuff: myValue];
```

I just want to make it like

```
[doStuff: myValue];
```

Is it ok to do that? Will I have any problem like crash or the app becoming crazy? 
Is there other alternatives to make this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objective-C is similar to C in this regard: you can always ignore values returned by functions/methods.

However, as in C, it is important to follow the semantics defined by the function or method. For instance, if a function/method returns a pointer and the caller is supposed to free the corresponding memory, the caller needs to store that pointer in a variable and then call free(variable). Similarly, if a function/method returns an Objective-C object that's owned by the caller, then the caller must either send -release or -autorelease to the returned object.

Comment: I think the best approach is this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. Methods don't have to return anything, it's completely optional. It's what the `void` return type is for:

```
- (void)doStuff:(int)myValue;
```

---

**Edited to add**

If you want to only return something sometimes and the method normally returns an object, simply return **`nil`**. You don't have to provide a receiver.

Comment: i think what Digital Robot wants is use the same method with a return value when she/he is actually not interested in that value at certain point during run time.

Comment: Edited in case that's what he means.

Answer (score 1):

It should be ok if you guarantee that memory management within this **doStuff** method is self-sustained. (i.e. you use things like **autorelease** when allocating any new stuff with that method so memory won't leak)

Answer (score 1):

```
- (myObject *) doStuff: x
```

here you need to declare x type also.like

```
-(myObject *)doStuff:(NSString *)myValue;
```

then if you declare a return type for function then you must return a value otherwise make it void.

If you declare a return type then this is not neccessary to recieve that value in a variable but function must return the value.

And also you can set the arrays values in this method but declare array globally. One thing more if you make `-(myObject *)doStuff:(NSString *)myValue;`

then it needs a object to call, for same class use self.
you cant call like this

```
[doStuff: myValue];
```

Comment: ok no problem it helps some new users who does same mistake with functions.